# ¿Por qué no puedo iterar sobre el grafo g?

Tags: java, gráficas, collection

Estoy haciendo una API para grafos que debe implementar nodos y sus arcos. La clase debe satisfacer el siguiente test, que no se puede modificar:

```
package tester;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import grafos.*;

public class Tester1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Graph<String, Integer> g = new Graph<String, Integer>();
        Node<String> n1 = new Node<String>("s0");
        Node<String> n2 = new Node<String>("s1");
        g.addAll(Arrays.asList(n1, n2, n1)); // no admite repetidos, considerando igualdad referencial
        g.connect(n1, 0, n1); // conectamos n1 con n1 a través de enlace con valor 0
        g.connect(n1, 1, n2);
        g.connect(n1, 0, n2);
        g.connect(n2, 0, n1);
        g.connect(n2, 1, n1);
        System.out.println(g); // El grafo contiene 2 nodos y 5 enlaces

        for (Node<String> n : g) // Colección de dos nodos (n1 y n2)
            System.out.println("Nodo "+n);
}

}
```

He desarrollado las siguientes clases para implementar el test:

Graph:

```
package grafos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Graph<T1, T2>{
    ArrayList<Node> nodes;
    ArrayList<Edge> connects;

    // constructor
    public Graph()
    {
        this.nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.connects  = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }
    //@Override
    public void addAll(List<Node> lst){

        for(Node<?> n:lst){
            if (!nodes.contains(n)){
                nodes.add(n);
            }

        }

    }
    public Node<?> getNode1(){
        return this.nodes.get(0);
        //System.out.println(a);
    }  

    public void connect(Node<?> a, Integer value, Node b){
        Edge e= new Edge(a,value,b);
        this.connects.add(e);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String salida= "Nodes: \n";
        String nameNodos = "";
        String edges = "";
        for(Node<?> n:this.nodes){
            nameNodos= nameNodos+n.getId()+" [" + n.getName()+ "]\n";

        }
        salida= "Nodes: \n"+nameNodos+"Edges: \n";
        for(Edge c:this.connects){
            //nameNodos= n.getConexiones().toString();
            edges+= "( " + c.getSrc().getId() + " --" + c.getValue() + "--> " + c.getDest().getId() + " )\n";
        }
        salida= salida + edges;

        return salida;
    }
}
```

Node:

```
package grafos;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node<T>{
    T name;
    private int id=0;
    private static int idCounter = 0;
    private ArrayList<Node> conexiones;

    // constructor
    public Node(T name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id= idCounter;
        conexiones= new ArrayList<Node>();
        idCounter++;
    }

    public T getName(){
        return this.name;
    }    
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }  
    public ArrayList<Node> getConexiones(){
        return conexiones;
    }
    public boolean isConnectedTo(Node n){

        return true;

    }
    public String toString(){
        return ( this.getId() + " ["+ this.getName() + "]\n");
    }

}
```

Edge:

```
package grafos;

public class Edge {
    Node<?> src, dest;
    int value;

    Edge(Node<?> src,int valor, Node<?> dest)
    {
        this.src = src;
        this.value = valor;
        this.dest = dest;
    }
    public Node<?> getSrc(){
        return this.src;
    }
    public Node<?> getDest(){
        return this.dest;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Cuando intento ejecutar el test, al llegar al bucle, me da error porque me dice que solo puedo iterar instancias de Iterable, pero entiendo que la lista de Nodes que hay en el grafo g debería serlo.

```
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

        at tester.Tester1.main(Tester1.java:23)
```

¿Cómo podría modificar el código de Graph, Node o Edges, sin tocar el tester para que fuese iterable?

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero creo que tienes que implementar la interfaz Iterable (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Comment: Siempre puedes usar la librería pública de JGrapht, la importas y puedes jugar con todas las cosas que ya están hechas.

Answer (score 1):

Como lo indica @Gonzalo-GC tu clase Graph debes implementar la interface Iterable, en la clase Graph en el caso de la prueba, es muy sencillo ya que solo desean recorrer los nodos en el grafo.
Tu clase Graph quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Graph<T1, T2> implements Iterable{
    //---------------------------------------Tu codigo-----------------------------

@Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return nodes.iterator();
    }

}
```